# Python's pow() function and fast exponentiation gives different answers

Tags: python, c, performance, pow, exponentiation

I am getting different answers for below two implementations in C and python.
In Python

```
print(pow(15, 47413144071, 94826288143))
```

Prints 1

But in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned long Power(unsigned long A, unsigned long B, unsigned long X)
{
    unsigned long res = 1;
    while( B > 0 )
    {
        if( B & 1UL )
        {
            res = ( res * A ) % X;
        }
        A = ( A * A ) % X;
        B >>= 1UL;
    }
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%lu", Power(15, 47413144071, 94826288143));
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:
893231448
Any Help Is Appreciated.

Comment: An `unsigned long` is only guaranteed to be able to represent values in the range `0` to `4294967295` (although the standard *permits* representing a larger range, it is not required).    Both the values `B` and `C` you are passing exceed that.    If your implementation provides a 32-bit `unsigned long` then the values passed will be reduced modulo `4294967296`.

Comment: I did that but it is still giving the output as mentioned above. Output: 893231448

Comment: `47413144071` -- Why did you assume that Python uses an `unsigned long` here?  Since you tagged this as `C++`, there is a `uint64_t` type that you could have used.

Comment: Used uint64_t also. Still its not working.

Comment: C does not have arbitrary-precision integers. You must either implement yourself, or use an external library, such as `gmp`.

Comment: @ShashankRai [Python has arbitrary length integers](https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/).  This goes back to my first comment -- you should not have assumed that Python used a fixed-size integer type.  But even then, Python implements arbitrary length integers programmatically using their own "library", no different than if you used a third-party C library to implement the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments `unsigned long` is only guaranteed for values up to 4294967295, and your B and X are larger, otherwise you get values mod 2^32 mod X instead of values mod X. For the inputs you could replace them by `unsigned long long`.

However, you don't only need B and X to be representable as `unsigned long long` but also `res*A` and `A*A`, and since `A` can be as large as `X-1` it does not suffice to use `unsigned long long` in C to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that your C code generates overflows even with `uint64_t` type.

I have just converted the C code into Python, adding an overflow test. The first value not representable as an `uint64_t` is 2**64 or 0x10000000000000000 or 18446744073709551616. So I tested all products before the mod operation:

```
def Power(A, B, X):
    res = 1
    step = 1
    while (B > 0):
        if B & 1:
            if (res * A) >= 0x1000000000000000:
                print("uint64_t overflow at res step", step)
            res = (res * A) % X
        if (A * A) >= 0x1000000000000000:
            print("uint64_t overflow at A step", step)
        A = (A * A) % X
        B >>= 1
        step += 1
    return res

>>> Power(15, 47413144071, 94826288143)
uint64_t overflow at A step 4
uint64_t overflow at A step 5
uint64_t overflow at A step 6
uint64_t overflow at A step 7
uint64_t overflow at A step 8
uint64_t overflow at A step 9
uint64_t overflow at res step 10
uint64_t overflow at A step 10
uint64_t overflow at A step 11
uint64_t overflow at res step 12
uint64_t overflow at A step 12
uint64_t overflow at A step 13
uint64_t overflow at res step 14
uint64_t overflow at A step 14
uint64_t overflow at A step 15
uint64_t overflow at A step 16
uint64_t overflow at res step 17
uint64_t overflow at A step 17
uint64_t overflow at res step 18
uint64_t overflow at A step 18
uint64_t overflow at A step 19
uint64_t overflow at res step 20
uint64_t overflow at A step 20
uint64_t overflow at A step 21
uint64_t overflow at A step 22
uint64_t overflow at A step 23
uint64_t overflow at A step 24
uint64_t overflow at A step 25
uint64_t overflow at res step 26
uint64_t overflow at A step 26
uint64_t overflow at A step 27
uint64_t overflow at res step 28
uint64_t overflow at A step 28
uint64_t overflow at A step 29
uint64_t overflow at A step 30
uint64_t overflow at A step 31
uint64_t overflow at A step 32
uint64_t overflow at res step 33
uint64_t overflow at A step 33
uint64_t overflow at res step 34
uint64_t overflow at A step 34
uint64_t overflow at A step 35
uint64_t overflow at res step 36
uint64_t overflow at A step 36
1
```

This definitely proves that the algo is correct (we get `1` in the end) but also that you get a number of overflows if you try to use 64 bits integers.

---

Long story made short, if you need to implement that in C, you need either a system having a `uint128_t` type, or use a multiprecision library like [gmplib](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: What should I do then?